# Azure-Extracting log values from the alerts

Tags: azure

I am trying to write an alert in the alerts monitoring service of Azure. This alert should send an email whenever is triggered, and this email should contain some values extracted directly from the log. Is this possible or there is no way to do this in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

From **Application Insights/Log Analytics** you can define alerts based on your own queries too.

[Here is a good example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitor-alerts-unified-usage)

> For e.g,
>
> Consider a scenario where you want to know when your web-based App
>   gives a response to users with code 500 (that is) Internal Server
>   Error. You would create an alert rule with the following details:
>
> Query: `requests | where resultCode == "500"`
>  Time period: 30
>   minutes
>  Alert frequency: five minutes
>  Threshold value: Greater
>   than 0
>
> Then alert would run the query every 5 minutes, with 30 minutes of
>   data - to look for any record where result code was 500. If even one
>   such record is found, it fires the alert and triggers the action
>   configured.

You can send these alerts be defining the [action group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-action-groups) to *an Voice call or SMS, send an email, call a webhook, send data to an ITSM tool, call a Logic App, send a push notification to the Azure app, or run an Automation runbook.*

Once the Email alert is sent it will include that particular condition which the alert is configured. Unfortunately, there is no way to Extract the logs from the Azure Alerts in the Email.

You can provide your own feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytic) If you want this feature to include in Azure